# Add custom phtml to local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, template, local.xml

With my `local.xml`, I am already able to add CSS and JS files. Now I want to add an `.phtml` file to the `rwd/default/layout/page.xml` file, but it won't work.

In the `page.xml` file, there is a block with the name 'header'. I have made a reference to it in my own `local.xml` file like this:

```
    <reference name="header">
         <block type="page/html_textblock" name="textblock" template="page/html/textblock.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

The block inside the reference points to the textblock.phtml file, which only contains the sentence:

```
hey there
```

How do I make this sentence show on the `page.xml`, without altering the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's two problems here in my opinion.

First, **referencing a block won't necessarily display it.**

It depends on the template of the block you're referencing.

In your case **`header.phtml` does not automatically renders all its child block** via the following code:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml();
```

Indeed, this template renders the block explicitely by passing the block name as an argument to the code above.

Thus **if you want to display your block you will have to modify the `header.phtml` and add the following code to it**:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('textblock');
```

On top of that **I don't think there's any `page/html_textblock` block type out of the box in Magento.**

If you want to display the **content of a template** you can do the following:

```
<block type="core/template" name="textblock" template="page/html/textblock.phtml"/>
```

If you just want to display **some hardcoded text** you can do the following:

```
<block type="core/text" name="textblock">
    <action method="setText">
        <text><![CDATA[Hey There]]></text>
    </action>
</block>
```

Comment: It worked very well, but is there also a way where I don't override the header.phtml file?

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen unfortunately if you're using the default `header.phtml` file and absolutely want to add that block to the header no there's no way because as I said, the default header template does not render all its child block automatically

Comment: Hmm, okay, well, thanks for your help anyway! Helped me alot

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen not a problem. Feel free to mark your question as answered so it will benefit for others ;)

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
<reference name="header">
     <block type="core/template" name="textblock" template="page/html/textblock.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: why core/template, if I may ask?

Comment: Also, it does not work yet :/

Comment: for that you need to understand what is block type in magento and if I write block/template it means it call `Mage_Core_Block_Template` class

Comment: Also Add this line in your theme header.phtml file `echo  $this->getChildHtml('textblock');`